# Angular when testing component ng test , Plotly object not found on window"

Tags: angular, angular-test, plotly.js

Error: Plotly object not found on window.

```
Error: Plotly object not found on window.
at new PlotlyViaWindowModule (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/angular-plotly.js/fesm2015/angular-plotly.js.js:634:1)
at Object.PlotlyViaWindowModule_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/angular-plotly.js/fesm2015/angular-plotly.js.js:639:74)
at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11457:1)
at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11276:1)
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11314:1
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at R3Injector._resolveInjectorDefTypes (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:11314:1)
at new NgModuleRef$1 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:25345:1)
at R3TestBedCompiler.finalize (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.js:926:1)
at TestBedRender3.get testModuleRef [as testModuleRef] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.js:1789:1)
```

first time i am writing unit test in angular , why this is coming i am not getting

in ng serve i am linking plotly file by script in main.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8888/../../../plotly.min.js"></script>
```

but in testing how can i include this file

this is all  i need to add this file

Answer (score 0):

open karma.config.js

go to config.set
and add the files array with the path of the required files

```
config.set({
files: ['path/plotly.min.js','path/for/other/if/needed/'
],
basePath: '',
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'), 
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage'),
  require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],
.....
 ....
});
```